# Update mapping not working on my index (elasticsearch 1.4)

Tags: json, elasticsearch, put

When I try to update my index, and add a new field created from the method copy_to (see http://pastebin.com/T7GcHSXj ), I get this error I don't understand:

> "error":"MapperParsingException[Root type mapping not empty after
>   parsing! Remaining fields:   [mappings :
>   {tInfoclient={properties={Client={properties={d_naiss_cli={type=string,
>   copy_to=full_info}, pr_cli_20={type=string, copy_to=full_info},
>   nom_cli_20={type=string, copy_to=full_info}, full_info={type=string},
>   dc_cli={format=dateOptionalTime, type=date},
>   no_coEmprunteur={type=string}, cmpl_voie_cli={type=string},
>   loc_cli={type=string}, no_tel_cli={type=string},
>   no_ctrat={type=string}, no_tel_empcli={type=string},
>   voie_cli={type=string}, c_post_cli={type=string},
>   c_qual={type=string}, ad_e_mail={type=string}, no_telp={type=string},
>   ptel_empcli={type=string}}}}}}]]","status":400}

I followed documentation from the website, but no clue:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/indices-put-mapping.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/custom-all.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating a mapping type you need to remove the `mappings` section and the type name since those are already specified in the URL:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://maprvm:9200/maprdb/_mapping/tInfoclient' -d '{
            "properties": {
                "Client": {
                    "properties": {
                        "d_naiss_cli": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "copy_to":  "full_info"
                        },
                        "pr_cli_20": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "copy_to":  "full_info"
                        },
                        "nom_cli_20": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "copy_to":  "full_info"
                        },
                        "full_info": {
                            "type":     "string"
                        },
                        "dc_cli": {
                            "format": "dateOptionalTime",
                            "type": "date"
                        },
                        "no_coEmprunteur": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "cmpl_voie_cli": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "loc_cli": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "no_tel_cli": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "no_ctrat": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "no_tel_empcli": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "voie_cli": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "c_post_cli": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "c_qual": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "ad_e_mail": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "no_telp": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "ptel_empcli": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

}'
```

Comment: i will accept this answer when it will be possible... feels bad when i misread the documentation :/